# How can I draw the inside of a box as well as the outside?

Tags: xna

I have a 3D box in which I have some holes. The thing is that when I look through the holes, I can't see the wall of the box that should appear as the inner wall.

How can I draw this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have backface culling enabled. It can be enabled with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.renderstate.cullmode%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) to *None*.

In XNA 4.0 : `GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;`